# How to add separator to kendo toolbar splitbutton menuitems

Tags: css, kendo-ui, toolbar

Kendo UI 2015.2.805

I want to add a separator line between menu items on the toolbars's split button dropdown.  I know how to add a separator line between toolbar buttons, as shown below, but it does not work for the menuButtons array.

```
$("#my_toolbar").kendoToolBar({
items: [
    { type: "button", text: "Option 1" },
    { type: "separator"},
    { type: "button", text: "Option 2" },
    { type: "splitButton", text: "Actions", 
        menuButtons: [
            { id: "button_3", text: "Option 3" },
            { id: "button_4", text: "Option 4" },
            //separator here
            { id: "button_5", text: "Option 5" },
            { id: "button_6", text: "Option 6" }
        ]
    }
  ]
});
```

`
How to add separator at the comment?

RESOLVED:

Posting David's solution here from his link so it's persisted. I needed to style the .no-button in my environment to collapse it to a line. Perfect.

```
.no-button { padding: 0;}

menuButtons: [
            { id: "button_3", text: "Option 3" },
            { id: "button_4", text: "Option 4" },
            { enable: false, attributes: { class: "no-button"} },
            { id: "button_5", text: "Option 5" },
            { id: "button_6", text: "Option 6" }
        ]
```

Comment: is this the kind of thing you are looking for: http://dojo.telerik.com/UlAfUZEg

Comment: Yes, that is very close.  I needed to add a padding: 0 to the .no-button class and now it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB way to do this. There are a few hacky ways to do it with your own markup. For example you can do something like this:

```
$("#my_toolbar").kendoToolBar({
items: [
    { type: "button", text: "Option 1" },
    { type: "separator"},
    { type: "button", text: "Option 2" },
    { type: "splitButton", text: "Actions", 
        menuButtons: [
            { id: "button_3", text: "Option 3" },
            { id: "button_4", text: "Option 4" },
            { text: "<hr style='margin:0px; padding:0px; color:#d8d8d8;' />", enable: false },
            { id: "button_5", text: "Option 5" },
            { id: "button_6", text: "Option 6" }
        ]
    }
  ]
});
```

The only problem with this is that it will get highlighted if you scroll over it, because it will get wrapped in an anchor element when it gets rendered. If that bothers you, then you could give the `hr` an id and then use JavaScript to find it, get its parent, and modify the css of the anchor.