# How to group (add horizontal line between) items of Kendo DropDownButton

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to add `<hr>` between two items of the Kendo DropDownButton. I guess I need something similar to [How to add separator to kendo toolbar splitbutton menuitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729718/how-to-add-separator-to-kendo-toolbar-splitbutton-menuitems) as the desired functionality is the same.

Html

```
<kendo-dropdownbutton aria-label="Actions" class="k-button" [disabled]="isLoading" [data]="actionsOptions" (dblclick)="toolBarButtondblclick()" style="padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px;"><span class="k-icon k-i-grid"></span>{{lbl_Actions}}</kendo-dropdownbutton>
```

Ts

```
this.actionsOptions = [
        {
            text: this.lbl_Copy,
            icon: 'copy',
            click: () => {
                this.copyAPHit();
            }
        },
        {
            text: this.lbl_ShowRelations,
            icon: 'connector',
            click: () => {
                this.showRelations();
            }
        },
        {
            disabled: (this.segmentsPath !== "APs"),
            text: this.lbl_UnSync,
            icon: 'non-recurrence',
            click: () => {
                this.unSync();
            }
        }
    ];
```

So, I need to add a horizontal line (separate) between the second and the third item. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using `kendoDropDownButtonItemTemplate` in HTML.

```
<kendo-dropdownbutton aria-label="Actions" class="k-button" [disabled]="isLoading" [data]="actionsOptions" (dblclick)="toolBarButtondblclick()" style="padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px;">
<span class="k-icon k-i-grid"></span>
{{lbl_Actions}}
<ng-template kendoDropDownButtonItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="k-icon k-i-{{ dataItem.icon }}"></span>
        <span>{{ dataItem.text }}</span>
        <hr *ngIf="dataItem.last" style="display: block; border: 1px solid #bebebe; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

The datasource in TS should then be modified a little bit:

```
this.actionsOptions = [
    {
        text: this.lbl_Copy,
        icon: 'copy',
        click: () => {
            this.copyAPHit();
        },
        last: true
    },
    {
        text: this.lbl_ShowRelations,
        icon: 'connector',
        click: () => {
            this.showRelations();
        }
    },
    {
        disabled: (this.segmentsPath !== "APs"),
        text: this.lbl_UnSync,
        icon: 'non-recurrence',
        click: () => {
            this.unSync();
        }
    }
];
```

where `last` is used to show the last item of a group and creates the desired horizontal row.